# django -- how to construct and initialize a complex model object with many depenencies

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that looks something like this:

```
class ChildClass(Model):
    # define fields

class ParentClass(Model):
    child1 = models.ForeignKey(ChildClass)
    child2 = models.ForeignKey(ChildClass)
    child3 = models.ForeignKey(ChildClass)
```

Every time I create an instance of ParentClass, I need to make sure that I have valid ChildClass objects for it. Is there a proper, or standard way to create these "dependency" objects? My current plan is to create the child objects in `__init__`, and save them in `save`, like this:

```
class ChildClass(Model):
    # define fields

class ParentClass(Model):
    child1 = models.ForeignKey(ChildClass)
    child2 = models.ForeignKey(ChildClass)
    child3 = models.ForeignKey(ChildClass)

    def __init__(self):
        child1 = ChildClass()
        child2 = ChildClass()
        child3 = ChildClass()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # save each child obejct if it hasn't been saved yet
        for child in [child1, child2, child3]:
            if child.pk is None:
                child.save()

        super(ParentClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at django signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/. Put a signal on the post_init signal for this model and have it create and associate the child models.

Here's a list of signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/

So for example:

```
@reciever(post_init, sender=ParentClass)
def on_parent_class_create(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    instance.child1 = ChildClass()
    etc...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Aeros. Is there an advantage of using a signal over what I've outlined in my question? Is using a signal actually better?

Comment: Well the nice thing is that you can break out this specific functionality into it's own function. In the future if you needed to add more stuff into the save function it may become pretty bloated. Same goes for the init function. Technically you can have many of these functions set as receivers to the post_init on ParentClass and then they can be broken into their purpose. I should have named the function something more specific to your use case.

Comment: Thanks. Was able to come up with a reasonably elegant solution to my problem using signals.